# Play Cannot connect to (PostgreSQL) database [default]

Tags: database, postgresql, playframework

I'm getting

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors: 
1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
[...]
2) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

Originally I had MySQL database used with Play Framework app which worked, but I wanted to change it to PostgreSQL and that's when problems started appearing. I've installed them both on my Ubuntu computer and changed play config to use Postgres (added `"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",` to build.sbt and changed db.default properties to reference Postgres). Exact `application.conf` is:

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/playdb"
db.default.username="luka"
db.default.password="test"
```

I have manually created user luka with password test and database playdb. I have tried with postgres user as well with no avail.

What bugs me more, MySQL won't work either now with the same error. I have created new project with only modifying db.default params in conf and it fails in the same manner. Commenting out `application.conf` makes it go away, so that's definitely the problem. I have checked PostgreSQL logs (`/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log`) and only line that doesn't seem right is `[unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`. It appears multiple times, but not every time I refresh project (I'm not even sure it's related). I have removed `mysql-server` from my PC hoping everything will magically fix itself. It didn't.

Ideas?

I'm using Play 2. 4. 6 and IntelliJ IDEA 15. Project is created using Activator and importing sources to IDEA (using SBT model).

**EDIT** I'm also getting errors when I add `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"` to my `application.conf`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, the definite answer is:

First, there's a mistake in the database url, it should be `db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/playdb"` as [chabeee pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34329332/2363015). It's the only correct format for `db.default.url` (so no `jdbc:postgresql://username:pasword:localhost/dbname` or similar, as I've seen suggesting on other places).

Second, more tricky, is that there's a bug in the driver as [Salem pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324036/2363015) and workaround is adding `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"` to `application.conf`.
However, that bug is fixed (well, that workaround is implemented) in versions more recent than `9.1-903`. The catch is, after version `9.1-901` postgresql changed its groupID in the repos and now it's referenced by `org.postgresql`. A better solution than the workaround would be updating dependencies to `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc4"` ([current version](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/), [MVNrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql)). Append the appropriate jdbc version to the most recent PostgreSQL driver (`4` for Java 6, `41` for Java 7, `42` for Java 8).

My final `application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/playdb" #the port is optional
db.default.username="luka"
db.default.password="test"
```

And `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42",
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

**UPDATE 2017:**
I have only now noticed that not long after writing this answer they changed versioning scheme and removed -jdbc[code] fragment, replacing it with .jre6, .jre7 or nothing, apparently meaning it's meant for the latest Java version (I haven't found anything supporting this claim, but it works). Yet again in February 2017 they [changed the version scheme again](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html#versioning) and jumped from major version 9 to 42, making the current version (as of 17 July 2017) denoted by `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.3"` (or, accordingly, `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.3.jre7"` / `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.3.jre6"`)

Comment: The workaround (over the bug you told about) made it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace

> JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured

Basically this is a problem with your driver (it does not support that method), but you should be able to work around it specifying a test query in your `application.conf`:

```
play.db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
```

Comment: That does indeed solve the original error, however it creates a new one: `play.db.default has type OBJECT rather than STRING` (it's on that line, I checked)

Comment: @Luke Try to use `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"` instead

Comment: I've tried that also. At first I thought it gives the same error, however the stack trace is different now: http://hastebin.com/hazoraradi.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/playdb"
```

to this:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/playdb"
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: My db.default.url is already `jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/playdb`

Comment: change it to postgresQL, so you are missing the 'q' and the 'l' characters

Comment: This actually solved the problem, but also Salem's workaround needs to be applied. I swear I have just copy-pasted that part, didn't cross my mind it'd be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance on a Mac, and do you have a postgresql .jar file in your `/Library/Java/Extensions` directory?

**Edit:** Sorry, I'm new. I encountered the "JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported" message while using Hikari on my Mac, and I solved it by locating and removing a JDBC3 .jar file in that extensions directory. I don't know how it got there (probably when I installed PostgreSQL or some related tool) but I found that it would get loaded instead of any JDBC4 .jar file on my classpath. Maybe something similar happens in Ubuntu. Probably worth checking, as other JDBC4-related problems could arise besides "isValid()".

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer to the question

Comment: Yes, comments are used for asking for clarification, answers should answer the question, not ask more of them. But to answer you, no, I'm on Ubuntu (and have solved the issue).

Comment: @Luke That didn't work for me sadly. I assumed there was some other work around.