# Play 2 postgres driver not found

Tags: postgresql, scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm doing a Scala Play 2 project in IntelliJ, and for some reason, the play framework wont recognize the Postgres driver.

```
Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Driver not found: [org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver}]]
```

My build.sbt is updated:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1206-jdbc42"
```

My application.conf has all the right stuff:

```
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://theurl:5439/mydb"
db.default.user="me"
db.default.password="thepassword"
```

Note that I have verified the username, password, and connection url separately - they work.

Things I have tried: (1) downloading the divers manually and putting them in my `lib` directory, (2) restarting/rebuilding the project, (3) changing the driver versions, and (4) implementing the solution for a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323835/play-cannot-connect-to-database-default) which involved adding the following line to my application.conf:

```
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
```

None of these things have worked, or even changed the error message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver you provided (`"org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"`) is incorrect. The correct one is `org.postgresql.Driver`.

### Details

According to the Play Docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaDatabase#PostgreSQL-database-engine-connection-properties) you need the following configuration:

```
# application.conf
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="....."
```